# Partial TypeScript Syntax highlighting in VS2015 compared to VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

How do I get the same syntax highlighting for TypeScript in VS2015 as Visual Studio code?

I noticed partial syntax highlighting as compared to VSCode

[image: Visual Studio Code]

[image: Visual Studio 2015]

I'm running VS2015 Update 3
and VSCode 1.8.1

Thank you ahead of time !

Comment: is IntelliSense working?

Comment: IntelliSense is working

Comment: Try run Visual Studio by `devenv /resetsettings` in commad line. If dont help try to reinstall TypeScript Tools For Visual Studio. Just download and install newer from http://www.typescriptlang.org/#download-links.

Comment: I tried both of those suggestions but still the same issue